# C code optimization query

Tags: c

I've a question about following C code.

```
struct pqr {
  int b;
};

struct abc {
  int a;
  struct pqr * ptr2;
};

struct abc *ptr1;

ptr1->ptr2->b = 10;
```

Now if I have several lines of code with ptr1->ptr2 dereferencing in a function,
will the following code change help reduce CPU cyles ?

```
   struct pqr *ptr = ptr1->ptr2;

   ptr->b = 10;
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the generated assembly for both the version? Do you see any difference?

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for `pqr* ptr2` to point at?

Comment: In how far might this be relevant for the answer?

Comment: The answer is "probably yes", but today's compilers are smart and they are really good at optimization, so maybe it won't make any difference. To be sure you need to look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: @Gerhardh If the pointer is accessed without being initialized or pointing at valid memory, then the code invokes undefined behavior. The compiler is then free to generate any form of machine code, or no machine code at all.

Comment: This will possibly depend on your compiler settings. To prevent [aliasing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), conservative compiler settings might force it to read the value each time to make sure it hasn't changed in between.

Comment: @Lundin: The question is about performance optimization. With only 1 line of actual code given it does not make much sense to talk about other topics.

Comment: @Lousy There exists no aliasing problems here. `ptr` is of type `struct pqr *ptr` and so is `ptr1->ptr2`. Pointer aliasing has nothing to do with the compiler making assumptions about if a variable has been used or not. Sounds like you are mixing it up with the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @Gerhardh My point is, if the compiler can deduct that `ptr1->ptr2` is uninitialized, it is free to complete ignore the whole code, or skip optimizations, or generate complete nonsense code, or crash and burn. It doesn't make sense to discuss optimization for code that invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin: here is an example, [Tasking C166 compiler](http://tasking.com/support/c166-classic/c166_v8.7.pdf), page 4−98, section 4.6. Alias: *"By default the compiler assumes that each pointer may point to any object created in the program, so when any pointer is dereferenced, all register contents are assumed to be invalid afterwards"*. Example 3 on next page is a simple example of how this particular compiler can produce two different assemblies (and the *default* behavior is not to cache pointer values in registers).

Comment: @Lousy That example does not have the slightest to do with this question.

Comment: @Lundin, you are right. But this is only possible close to the location where the pointer is assigned. This would be some strict limitation to the relevance of the answer. For a more general answer the compiler cannot deduct this in most places.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough code shown to tell.

If it's all in one function it should make no difference. If you're passing two of the `struct pqr` into a function then cross function/module alias analysis becomes necessary to determine whether caching the pointer preserves the program semantics.

Comment: I dropped the memory allocation part to keep code fragment small. As I mentioned in the original post, there are several lines using ptr1->ptr2 deferencing, with ptr1->ptr2->b = 10 being just one sample line.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the compiler, but several known compilers *will* benefit from this explicit optimization in your code.

For this example code:

```
int getValue() {
  return rand();
}

void testA() {
  ptr1->ptr2->b = getValue();
  ptr1->ptr2->b = getValue();
  ptr1->ptr2->b = getValue();
}

void testB() {
  struct pqr *ptr2 = ptr1->ptr2;
  ptr2->b = getValue();
  ptr2->b = getValue();
  ptr2->b = getValue();
}
```

Both [GCC 6.3](https://godbolt.org/g/9h8Ho2) and [Clang 3.9.1](https://godbolt.org/g/e92cVu) with -O3 will produce assembly similar to this:

```
testA():
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR ptr1[rip]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rax+8] // load
        call    rand            
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], eax   // store

        mov     rax, QWORD PTR ptr1[rip]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rax+8]  // load
        call    rand            
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], eax  // store

        mov     rax, QWORD PTR ptr1[rip]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rax+8]  // load
        call    rand            
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], eax  // store


testB():
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR ptr1[rip]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rax+8]   // load

        call    rand
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], eax  // store

        call    rand
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], eax  // store

        call    rand
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbx], eax  // store
```

Comment: I upvoted, but it would be good to see the assembly with no optimisation.

Comment: @cdcdcd: check the links from the answer (Compiler Explorer: [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/9h8Ho2), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/g/e92cVu)) and clear the text box next to the compiler drop down box. In all cases I've checked `testA` accesses `ptr1` three times, and `testB` only once.

Comment: Sorry Lousy being lazy. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

On non optimized compilers, that will help. But in modern compilers, with optimization flags, you should not see the difference between the 2 syntaxes.

Comment: It may be true for single line `ptr->b = 10;`. But if there are 2+ `ptr->XXX` below it will be different.

Comment: That may depend on whether the compiler can prove the absence of aliasing.

Comment: @i486 No, an optimizing compiler is smart enough to introduce temporary variables where needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, such code will not improve performance. Any half-decent compiler will optimize away that temporary variable. Any of your versions will compile into machine code like the following:

store ptr1->ptr2 in index register x
...
do stuff with contents pointed at by index register x
...
// subsequent use of the same variable will use index register x

---

Your temporary variable could however improve readability, if you are going to use that nested struct a lot in several expressions. Replacing code like

```
something->something->something->x = 5;
if(something->something->something->x == something->something->something->y)
  something->something->something->y = 42;
```

with

```
something_t* s = something->something->something;
s->x = 5;
if(s->x == s->y)
  s->y = 42;
```

is quite an improvement of readability. But it will yield the very same machine code.

Comment: Using slightly more conservative compiler flags (regarding strict aliasing) might easily force it to read the address on each access (at least my experience with embedded/microcontroller assembly).

Comment: @Lousy Strict aliasing has nothing to do with this. All pointer types in the examples are compatible.

Comment: Aliasing could matter though. There could easily be two pointers to the same object in scope

Comment: @Lundin: it's not related to *strict* aliasing, I didn't express my self clearly enough, it's related to [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing). A different thread/interrupt can easily change the contents of `ptr2` during the execution of your example. The "improvement in readability" doesn't functionally equal code, as soon as your device has more than a single interrupt. For example, Tasking C166 compiler for microcontrollers assumes all registers to be invalid after each pointer dereference (unless you explicitly tell it to use relaxed caching).

Comment: @Lousy Multi-threading/multi-processors is a different topic entirely. Introducing temporary variables will not improve nor break such code. The code `struct pqr *ptr = ptr1->ptr2;` does not necessarily mean that the compiler will de-reference that variable - it does not have to since it was not declared as `volatile`. It can optimize away the temporary variable `ptr` entirely since it can deduct that this variable is not used. Note that the `volatile` keyword can protect against optimizer mishaps, but does not necessarily guarantee memory barrier behavior.

Comment: Here is a comparison of both codes [gcc 6.3 -O3](https://godbolt.org/g/9h8Ho2) and [clang 3.9.1](https://godbolt.org/g/e92cVu).

Answer (score 0):

How many instructions a compiler will output, for the case you've presented, will depend on the degree of optimisation (but here you assume none?), how smart your compiler is and the type of processor (CISC or RISC for example). As you can tell there are just too many variables to get an answer here. You'll need to disassemble and see if different version of your code produces compilations with more or less instructions (and for the offending lines of code only).

But generally in the past, advice was always that any form of "indirection" should be avoided if you were doing it inside a loop or within a function that was being called from within a loop. The reason is that the compiler may implement a number of operations in order to resolve indirection - so even if it mightn't look like your strictly dereferencing a pointer in C code, the compiler will produce assembly that will do - if you wish to use any of a structures members that is. Therefore, in your case it will need to resolve two levels of indirection rather than one (the alternative: ptr->b).

Answer (score -1):

I think it will help to reduce CPU cycles. `ptr` is pointer variable and `ptr1->ptr2` value cannot be calculated at compile time. At least the readability is better (with `ptr`).